# MFC C++: does setfocus set the capture as well?

Tags: c++, mfc, setfocus

I have a CDialog that is calling DoModal(), the dialog is opened, everything else is disabled, but for some reason I have only the keyboard capture and not the mouse.

The mouse capture is still on the last item it was on.

If I call setfocus before the DoModal, it doesn't work, but if I do setCapture before the DoModal it works.

Can anyone explain it to me?

What is the problem? I want to understand why I need to call to setCapture or releaseCapture before the DoModal (btw- releaseCapture works as well...)

Comment: I take it you mean `SetCapture` and not `SetCaption`? If so, you might want to edit your post and fix that; if not, your question makes no sense to me, I'm afraid. :)

Comment: eladyanni22 - we really need more information.  You're using the terms mouse and keyboard capture in a non-sensical fashion (see rodrigo's answer - he's correct).  Normally one doesn't ever call any sort of capture functions when calling DoModal.  Also, it's rare to call DoModal outside of the calling context (i.e. the function that creates an instance of your dialog, then calls that dialog's DoModal in order to "run" the dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'keyboard capture'. There is just keyboard focus.

A window that has the keyboard focus is the one that receives the keyboard related messages.
Mouse messages are normally sent to the window just beneath the mouse cursor, without regard to the focus. That is unless the mouse is "captured", in this case mouse messages are sent to the windows that has captured the mouse, no matter where the mouse cursor is.

That said, do you really need to capture the mouse? Actually that is rarely necessary. And it should be done only as a consequence to a user action, never on your own.

PS. Due to security concerns, in Windows there are actually two different kinds of mouse captures:

- Local captures: mouse messages are sent to the capturing window, only if the mouse is over a window that belongs to the same application.
- Global capture: mouse messages are sent to the capturing window, no matter where the mouse cursor is.

The `SetCapture` function creates a global capture only if it is called while processing a WM_?BUTTON_DOWN message.

Comment: just so i understand... if i do a: 'setCapture' on a window, it will keep the mouse input focus inside my application until i will call 'releaseCapture' or 'setCapture' on another window??

Comment: @eladyanai22 No, there is not such thing as "mouse focus" either. Remember, there are just "keyboard focus" and "mouse capture". And a mouse capture has severe security restrictions that prevents it to be used as a general force-focus mechanism. Mouse capture is intended mainly for drag-n-drop (or similar) operations that want to drop outside of the source window. Anything else is a road to frustration.